# How to find whole cluster size in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, disk-space, database-size

I know how to find relation and database size using `pg_total_relation_size()`, and `pg_database_size()`. But I want to find whole cluster size. Is there a way other than calculating disk space of `data` directory using file manager or using a query like this?

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_database_size(datname))) AS "total databases size"
FROM pg_database;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also [`pg_tablespace_size()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#id-1.5.8.33.9.3.2.2.9.1.1.1):

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_tablespace_size(oid))) AS "total cluster size"
FROM pg_tablespace;
```

It should report slightly more than the sum of database sizes as it also includes global objects (which don't normally account for much).